# Get topic id from Google Trends for a topic name using Python

Tags: python, google-trends

Using Python, I am attempting to scrape data from Google Trends for "topics" (as opposed to "search terms").

I am currently using the `pytrends` module, but it appears it's not (currently) possible to scrape topics rather than search terms, unless you know the `topic_id`.

E.g. if you wanted to scrape the data for the `topic_name` "Holiday", you could search using the `topic_id` `/m/03gkl`, but only if you knew that that was the `topic_id`.

I have a list of topic names. I would like a corresponding list of topic ids. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I didn't read the `pytrends` documentation properly and it is possible to get the topic id:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)
suggs = pytrends.suggestions("iron")
print(suggs)

[{'mid': '/m/025rw19', 'title': 'Iron', 'type': 'Chemical element'},
 {'mid': '/m/04jphh9', 'title': 'Clothes iron', 'type': 'Topic'},
 {'mid': '/m/0b6l369', 'title': 'Loha', 'type': '1987 film'},
 {'mid': '/m/03cld36', 'title': 'Iron', 'type': 'Golf'},
 {'mid': '/m/0281ql7', 'title': 'Ferric', 'type': 'III'}]
```

From the above, it is easy to extract the topic id.